# How to use getattr() with dynamic object?

Tags: python, object, getattr

I need to get the attribute of different objects to print your content.
I thought about using the object argument dynamically, is it possible?

```
content = getattr("%s" % (variable), "attribute")
```

Comment: Not quite sure what your actual question is.

Comment: I think you're trying to do this? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9437726)

Comment: no that does not work (your solution, the previous comment works perfectly), you need the object not a string with the object name, try something like getattr(globals()[variable], "attribute_name")

Comment: If you have the name of a variable in a string, you're already doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class Custom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pet = 'dog'

my = Custom()

variable = 'my'
print(getattr(globals()[variable], 'pet'))
```

Output:

```
dog
```

Comment: Nonetheless, do heed chepner's remark to your question.

Comment: I now see E.Serra already posted this method in a comment to your question.